# Adding menu support in wordpress - css not being recognized though

Tags: php, css, wordpress

website: http://www.telugumovieshub.com/

I followed this tutorial here (except for creating a child theme): http://50dollarblogs.net/wordpress-menus-support/ to add menu support to my theme (coremag) which did not support it.

It did add the menu support as needed. My issue is that the css that I have added to my style.css is not being recognized at all.

```
#navigation ul#menu-main-menu{
display: block;
height: auto;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%}

#navigation ul#menu-main-menu li.current_page_item a:link, 
#navigation ul#menu-main-menu li.current_page_item a:active, 
#navigation ul#menu main-menu li.current_page_item a:visited {
background-color: #525252;
border-style: none;
border-width: 0;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
height: auto;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 6px 9px;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;}
```

I have left the current nav menu there to show the look that I am trying to achieve.

Thanks for any help.

Ken

Comment: Can we see a URL to the page in action, or the generated HTML from the menu? I'm betting the class and ID references are not being passed, or are different from what's specified in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the reference to your style sheet after the reference to the Wordpress sheet? There does not appear to be a reference to stylesheet.css in your source code anywhere.

-- So there are no elements with id="navigation"

Comment: Sorry, I meant style.css (where it is actually pulling what little css is there now), edited op.

Comment: Can you use view source and find your css from the browser, because I can't find it. What is the exact text of the reference?

Comment: line 6 using FF. <link href="http://www.telugumovieshub.com/wp-content/themes/coremag/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: +1 for missing #navigation element, I did not catch that!

Comment: there are no elements with id="navigation" i think you need to change the selectors to something like ul#menu-main li

Answer (score 0):

The UL being generated has ID `#menu-main`. Simply change your CSS references from `#menu-main-menu` to `#menu-main` and you should see the styling.

You're also missing a hyphen in the last reference `#navigation ul#menu main-menu li.current_page_item a:visited`.

```
#menu-main{
display: block;
height: auto;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%
}

#menu-main li.current_page_item a:link, 
#menu-main li.current_page_item a:active, 
#menu-main li.current_page_item a:visited {
background-color: #525252;
border-style: none;
border-width: 0;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
height: auto;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 6px 9px;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I see u removed all 'ul's in your edited code there. Was that intentional? Removing the '-menu' didn't change anything :(

Comment: I did, since you're calling the element by its ID, and an ID is only to be used once on any given page, you need not specify what type of element. Did you upload the changed file? Your `dropmenu.css` and `style.css` live on the server still show `#navigation ul#menu-main-menu` for me

Comment: #navigation #menu-main {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#navigation #menu-main li.current_page_item a:link, #navigation #menu-main li.current_page_item a:active, #navigation #menu-main li.current_page_item a:visited {
    background-color: #525252;
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
}

Comment: Looks good, if you remove the parent selector `#navigation ` things ought to be in good working order. As noted in the answer below me, there doesn't appear to be an element with ID="navigation" containing `#menu-main` :)

Comment: Ok, i removed #navigation, it does seem to be pulling the css from the right place now. But it still looks the same. I copied the css from the nav menu below the one we are working on. Was hoping it looked the same..lol

Comment: Ok, I got it guys. Thanks so much for both of your's help.